# Android App Publishing - "No devices supported"

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, manifest, publish

Below is my android manifest. Can anyone help me as to why my app apparently doesnt support any devices when the apk is uploaded to the android play/dev console?
I have included supports/compatible screens, however I am aware that only one is required. I have no "false" values/attributes and all my permissions are correct etc.

I realise this could be a duplicate, however, the only ones I've found are issues I don't have (the false attribute etc) or only for a specific device that the app doesn't support.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="PACKAGE.NAME"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="0.1.4">

    <supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <compatible-screens>
        <!--Only hdpi and xhdpi for normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all large size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

        <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
        <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

    </compatible-screens>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.feature.CAMERA"
        android:required="true"
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name="NAME"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logoapp"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data android:name="assist-host" android:value="IP_ADDRESS"/>
        <meta-data android:name="assist-port" android:value="PORT_NO"/>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main"/>
        <activity android:name=".InCallActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

        <activity android:name=".ResolutionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_resolution" />
        <activity android:name=".CameraSelectionActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_camera_selection" /> 

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".PreferencesActivity"/>

        <activity android:name=".ActivityLAInCall"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

        <service android:name=".RingtoneBackgroundService"/>
        <service android:name=".AssistService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: `android.feature.CAMERA` this seems like a incorrect permission! Correct is `android.hardware.camera`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

for more info of supports-screens read this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#requiresSmallest)

remove this if your app not support tablets `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"`

---

remove compatible-screens element from manifest because

***Caution:*** Normally, you should not use this manifest element **compatible-screens** . Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and densities.

read more here [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

**so, REMOVE BELOW CODE FROM ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />

</compatible-screens>
```

***after doing this you app support more then 8000 devices :)***

also change this `android.feature.CAMERA` to `android.hardware.camera`, if camera must not needed then change this `android:required="true"` to `android:required="false"`

Comment: This worked, thank you. I believe the main issue to be the camera. Damn copy and paste!

Comment: i think main issue in `compatible-screens`, i will try with wrong future and let you know after some time. what happened

Comment: I tried without the screens extra before and that didn't work either, the only common thing was the feature.camera. I've uploaded to play store now and it works. :-) 6000 supported devices.